# React JS: How should I manage a data refresh when compement updates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React, and I wanted to re-request data to a REST server after login in case of "session expired error".

When the component mounts, it fetches the data from the network. However, if session has expired, I receive an unauthorized error. This error is managed by a parent component, which shows the login form to reactivate session. I did that like this because I have many components that should behave like that (re-request after login).

```
<Parent>
 <Component1/>
 <Component2/>
 ...
</Parent>
```

If a "session expired error" is triggered Parent's state changes and it shows the login form. After login, Parent's state changes again and all visible components should update their data. The ComponentX method called when Parent's state is changed is ComponentWillUpdate and ComponentDidUpdate, so I placed the following code in ComponentWillUpdate:

```
if (!this.state.gotData && !this.updating){
    this.updating = true;
    this.setState({gotData:true}, 
        ()=>{this.updating=false; this.getData();});
}
```

which does the following: if it was not able to get the data from the network and it is not getting data at the moment (!this.updating flag), it requests the data through this.getData method. gotData is updated in optimistic assumption, and it is set to false if getData method fails.

I know that setState should not be used in componentWillUpdate method, but I have not found a better solution to this. Maybe I could add a validSession prop to all components, then set it to false when "Parent" gets the "expiration" error, and set it to true when login is done. And re-request data from in componentWillReceiveProps instead of componentWillUpdate.

Another possible solution would be to subscribe components to a global "re-login" event, and do the data request inside the listener.

How would you do that? Maybe my approach is completely wrong from the beginning...

Comment: are u using redux?

Comment: No, I am not, I haven't seen any need until now.

Comment: I'm asking that because with redux you could just emit an action that your login session has expired and then update your state. Whenever you need to check if the session is expired, just need to read from the updated state. And also just emit an action to reload your data. The update in your components will be transparent, you know?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll take that into account. This is my first react project, and I decided not using redux until I saw a real need. Perhaps the moment has come :-)

Comment: I see. Very wise.. hahaha. But give redux a chance... hehe.